# Need distinct value based on id when we JOIN 4 tables in PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, join, distinct

Here is my SQL query which joins 4 tables and it works correctly.

```
SELECT pl.lms_id, u.id,  REPLACE(trim(u.`url`), 'www.', '') AS url, trim(u.`name`) as name, p.date_removed, p.status, p.ignore_status FROM `adl_seo_status` p INNER JOIN `adl_user_profiles` u on p.profile_id = u.id  INNER JOIN adl_tw_profile_acc_type ac on p.profile_id = ac.profile_id LEFT JOIN `adl_lms_prof_list` pl on u.id = pl.profile_id  WHERE u.`vpg_id`='2' AND u.`status` = 'Y' and ac.acc_type_id = '2' ORDER BY u.`url` ASC, p.id DESC
```

I am facing an issue that, the table **adl_seo_status** has multiple entries for a single profile_id. So, that accounts are repeating in my listing. I want that account as a single row which means the distinct value of accounts based on profile_id.

Comment: In your select, are the rows of repeating accounts identical or can have some differing field? If they are identical, you could add DISTINCT after SELECT. I think that should work. If not, you can use group by the repeating fields and use some aggregate function to concat (i.e.) the other fields. To sum up, if your rows are identical, DISTINCT, if not you'll have to group.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use group by, for example:

```
SELECT
  pl.lms_id,
  u.id,
  REPLACE(trim(u.`url`), 'www.', '') AS url,
  trim(u.`name`)                     AS name,
  p.date_removed,
  p.status,
  p.ignore_status
FROM `adl_seo_status` p INNER JOIN `adl_user_profiles` u ON p.profile_id = u.id
  INNER JOIN adl_tw_profile_acc_type ac ON p.profile_id = ac.profile_id
  LEFT JOIN `adl_lms_prof_list` pl ON u.id = pl.profile_id
WHERE u.`vpg_id` = '2' AND u.`status` = 'Y' AND ac.acc_type_id = '2'
ORDER BY u.`url` ASC, p.id DESC GROUP BY p.profile_id;
```